# How to delete a portlet in Liferay 6.1 programmatically from code

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

**I'm working on Liferay 6.1**
I want to delete a portlet in Liferay 6.1 from my code.
What I have done so far is:

```
<a onclick="Liferay.Portlet.close('#p_p_id_28_'); return false;">Remove</a>
```

Above code is working fine. But it is working on the current page only i.e. it can delete the portlet(s) which is there on the current page only.

But I want to delete the portlet(s) which could be some where on the menu of my portal using its layout id.

Please suggest a way out.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Varun Jain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void removePortlets(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
            throws PortletException {
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request
                .getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
        String friendlyURL = "/demochildpage";
        boolean privateLayout = false;
        long userId = themeDisplay.getUserId();
        try {
            Layout layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLLayout(
                    groupId, privateLayout, friendlyURL);
            LayoutTypePortlet layoutTypePortlet = (LayoutTypePortlet) layout
                    .getLayoutType();
            layoutTypePortlet.removePortletId(userId, "28");
            LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout(layout.getGroupId(),
                    layout.getPrivateLayout(), layout.getLayoutId(),
                    layout.getTypeSettings());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I want to delete the portlet(s) which could be some where on the menu of my portal using its layout id" Not clear relationship with your answer.

Comment: The above logic would remove portlet just from the demochildpage page.

Comment: For demo purpose, I was deleting the portlet on this page only but it can be dynamically deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Way to go would be:
query the database for all Layouts on which the portlet is on, than iterate and delete. 
You would need to implement a custom query or a dynamic query if I am not overseeing something. Maybe there already is a service function to get the desired Layout Id's, but I doubt that.

Comment: Hey Gevatterjan,

This is a good idea ad I tried it as well but the problem is that it removes the portlet(s) only after re-starting the server. I tried other things as well and one of them worked fine and I've pasted it over here as answer. So you can take a look at it.
btw thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried, but I think, you can achieve what you want using Liferay's service.

The process seems to be simple enough as following: 
**1.** Get list of all pages / layouts using `com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayouts(long groupId, boolean privateLayout)` 
**2.** Iterate layout list and extract list of portletIds from layout object casted to `com.liferay.portal.model.LayoutTypePortlet` 
**3.** Iterate portletIds and compare each porteltId with your portletId string. 
**4.** If matched call `com.liferay.portal.model.layoutTypePortlet.removePortletId(long userId, String portletId)` and update layout using `LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout(Layout layout)`

So, the sample code would look like:

```
String portletId = "#p_p_id_28_";
long userId = user.getUserId();
ArrayList<Layout> layouts = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayouts(10180, true);

for(Layout layout : layouts){
    if(!layout.isHidden()){
        LayoutTypePortlet layoutTypePortlet = (LayoutTypePortlet) layout.getLayoutType();
        ArrayList<String> layoutPortletIds = layoutTypePortlet.getPortletIds();

        for(String layoutPortletId : layoutPortletIds){
            if(layoutPortletId.equalsIgnoreCase(portletId)){
                layoutTypePortlet.removePortletId(userId, portletId);
                LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout(layout);
            }
        }
    }
}
```